# Windows Phone 8 App support for 1080p resolution

Tags: windows-phone-8, emulation

As I noticed, Microsoft has announced a couple of devices (e. g. Lumia 1520) which have fullHD screen. But in my Visual Studio 2012 I have only three resolution options (WVGA, WXGA and HD720P). Is it possible to enable support for fullHD phones, which constant should I add into the following piece of manifest:

```
<ScreenResolutions>
  <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_WVGA" />
  <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_WXGA" />
  <ScreenResolution Name="ID_RESOLUTION_HD720P" />
</ScreenResolutions>
```

Also, is there an emulator available for 1080p resolution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's available now, you can now run your WindowsPhone8 app in 1080p resolution emulator, Microsoft just released an update for it, read the [Windows Phone Developer Blog](http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/wpdev/archive/2014/01/02/new-emulators-available-for-windows-phone-8-0-updates-2-and-3.aspx)

Comment: Note that usage of `<ScreenResolutions>` in the manifest is obsoleted in 8.1